# When importing cv2, there is libgio2.0 error at python 3.7, Anaconda 4.9.2

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, opencv

When importing **opencv2**, there is **libgio2.0** error. Can you help me to handle this error?

```
(py37) usr@usr:~$ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/kca/anaconda3/envs/py37/bin/../lib/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_unix_get_passwd_entry
>>>
```

**Distributions:**
Anaconda 4.9.2, python 3.7.9, ubuntu 18.04